# Access applications and their folders from terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I have a folder that I want to init with git, but to do that I have to 'navigate' to that folder using cd. The problem is when I write `cd Applications`, that folder is empty and I cannot go into following folders.

The path I want to access is `/Application/MAMP/htdocs`.

I am using OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: You really don't want to put a folder under /Applications under git - nothing in that directory should change

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the current directory is `~/`, `cd Applications` goes to `~/Applications/` (which doesn't exist by default, but I guess you have an empty folder there). Try adding a slash to the start: `cd /Applications/`.

Comment: Thanks user495470! This solution works for me. But I don't really understand your answer. Can you explain it in more newb terms for my layman level?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the application, click on "Show Package Contents".
2. once the folder is displayed, navigate it to your required folder.
3. select that file and move it on Terminal and drop it there.

Example:

```
cd /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.2016.2.5.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn
```

Answer (score 1):

The Application folder that you want is at the Root directory. To go to this root directory, do "cd /" after that , you can do "cd Applications" to go into the applications folder.

The Applications folder you are going into is in your Home directory. To see the full location of the current directory use "pwd". This directory will be having an empty "Applications" folder - which you are going into when you typed "cd Applications"

Comment: Alternatively just do `cd /Applications`

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to the question but gets you to the required subfolder (path) inside 'Applications' with Terminal easily and fast.

- Use Finder and navigate to the folder you want
- Hover over the folder
- Right click
- Select 'New Terminal at Folder'

You are now `cd`(ed) to the folder you want.

[image: Screenshot of a Finder window with a folder selected, the contextual menu open, and 'New Terminal at Folder' option selected]